# CodeRush naming convention

Tags: coderush

I am evaluating CodeRush and what I am missing is name convention checking. I have used ReSharper before and it automatically checks names of classes, properties, methods and etc. For example properties name for first uppercase letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default CodeRush settings are available via

**DevExpress\Options (Ctrl+Shift+Alt+O)**

then

**Editor \ CodeStyle \ Identifiers**

From this page you can configure **Fields, Locals and Parameters**.

CodeRush also supports a rich eco-system of plugins.

In your case you'd likely be interested in this [StyleNinja Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/dxcorecommunityplugins/wiki/CR_StyleNinja)